# Get_the_post_thumbnail в wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Вот нашел статью по `get_the_post_thumbnail` в wordpress, но я все равно не понимаю, как передать `$attr`, а точнее

```
'alt'  => trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_excerpt )), 
'title'=> trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_title )),
```

Как уже только не пробовал.

Может, подскажете? Вот [статья](http://wp-kama.ru/function/get_the_post_thumbnail).

Comment: Все еще нужна помощь.

Comment: $attr массив же

Comment: Все еще не получается и даже представления не имею, как настроить get_the_post_thumbnail. Нужна помощь

Answer (score 0):

Добавляем в функции темы строку:

`add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`

Далее, корректный вызов, сначало даем нужные доп.параметры:

`$attrs = [
    'alt'   => trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_excerpt )),
    'title' => trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_title ))
];`

`get_the_post_thumbnail([id нужного поста],[нужный зарегистрированный размер], $attrs);`

Часть в атрибуте `alt` `trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_excerpt ))` например, в даном случае, возмет описание прикрепленного изображения к посту с `[id нужного поста]`, тоесть если оно не заполнено то будет пустым, аналогично с атрибутом `title`. Рекомендую проверить описание картинки, её название(title) и прочее в панели администрирования в разделе "Медиа" нажав на картинку, которую Вы прикрепили к посту в блоке `Featured Image`.

Очень простой тест работы, это в масиве параметров написать

`'alt'   => 'Мой тест!'`

Тогда, после загрузки странице посмотреть в инспекторе результат, если все правильно `alt` у изображения будет `Мой тест!`